# Different Way to use Using

Tags: c#

It's been a hot minute since I've used C# and Visual Studio today gave me a code suggestion that I don't quite understand regarding using. It suggested the following code segment:

```
            try
            {
                using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await dto.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
                }
            }
```

Get simplified to the following:

```
            try
            {
                using var stream = new MemoryStream();
                await dto.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            }
```

I thought that the object in after the using statement was disposed of after the closing brace that you are supposed to include. Does using actually work more like a scope guard in C++ RAII where it's going to dispose of the object after whatever closing braces it is in?

Thanks!

Comment: C# 8.0 syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 2):

This is new C# 8 syntax you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using).

According to the documentation:

> The lifetime of a using local will extend to the end of the scope in which it is declared. The using locals will then be disposed in the reverse order in which they are declared.